# What is a simple way to duplicate and transform an extracted CSS file in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

Using the css loader to create a .css file in a dist folder, how would you  then copy this file to a new file name and apply a transform?

webpack.config.plugins:

```
new ExtractTextPlugin('../dist/[name].css'),
new CopyWebpackPlugin([ // doesn't work, but this is what I want to accomplish
  {
    from: path.resolve('./dist/[name].css'),
    to: path.resolve('./dist/[name].transformed.css'),
    transform: css => transformed(css)
  }
]),
```

Seems like there is either a timing issue or something I don't quite get yet about how plugins work.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways in which the plugins are executed.
However the simplest is the synchronous approach where in the Webpack plugins are executed in a sequence, something similar to the lifecycle methods in React. So, there are some standard set of methods which are invoked in a particular order.

Please refer [Webpack Plugin API](https://webpack.js.org/api/plugins/).

If you are running webpack dev server, the file will not be copied to the specified destination, as it maintains all the files in the memory.

`CopyWebpackPlugin` is supposed to work with the way of your implementation. You just have to verify the source and destination paths. I see some discrepancy with the paths above.

```
new ExtractTextPlugin('../dist/[name].css'),
new CopyWebpackPlugin([ // doesn't work, but this is what I want to accomplish
  {
    from: path.resolve('./dist/[name].css'), // maybe this should be ../dist/[name].css
    to: path.resolve('./dist/[name].transformed.css'), // ../dist/[name].transformed.css
    transform: css => transformed(css)
  }
]),
```

Comment: Actually, this still fails. When the `CopyWebpackPlugin` runs, the file `'dist/css/[name].css'` does not yet exist.

Comment: It has to be ```'../dist/css/[name].css'```.

Comment: That code works  as long as the first CSS file exists before hand. The paths are OK. The part I can't figure out is the timing or if this is the right approach. Thanks for looking